# How to redirect from One page to Another

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a .NET developer but newbie in Angular js and PHP, I want to redirect to another page after saving the data. Here is the following code which i had written, what should i do for that

```
      var url = domain+"/index.php/welcome/insert2?email="+$scope.uemail+"&name="+$scope.uname+"&make="+$scope.umake.id+"&model="+$scope.umodel.id+"&mobile="+$scope.umobile+"&car_reg_no="+$scope.car_regist+"&pincode="+$scope.upincode;
       //$log.log(url);
       $ionicLoading.show();
       $scope.submitData(url).then(function(data){
            $log.log(data);
            $localstorage.set("uid",data);
                           $ionicLoading.hide();
       });
    }

   };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are not using transitionTo method.which is used to do that work. Here is the code snippet you should write after this line

```
 $localstorage.set("uid",data);
```

write

```
 $state.transitionTo('app.pagename');
```

Check if it works.

Comment: If it had worked then accept the answer so that others can get benefit.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `window.location.href = "URL"` to redirect browser to another page
2. Or Angular router if you want redirect to angular page. How to do it depends on what Angular router do you use:

`$state.go('app.page')` for standard router for example

Comment: Well Thanks but i would like to do that in Angular way

Comment: what kind of router do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code look like given below code-sample

```
var url = domain+"/index.php/welcome/insert2?email="+$scope.uemail+"&name="+$scope.uname+"&make="+$scope.umake.id+"&model="+$scope.umodel.id+"&mobile="+$scope.umobile+"&car_reg_no="+$scope.car_regist+"&pincode="+$scope.upincode;
   //$log.log(url);

   $ionicLoading.show();

   $scope.submitData(url).then(function(data){
        $log.log(data);
         $localstorage.set("uid",data);
   })
  .finally(function () {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      // Set URL here to redirect other page.
     $state.transitionTo('URL');

  });
};
```